# Entity Framework Core. Disable concurrency check for specific statements

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5, ef-core-5.0

I am using `EF Core 5` with `.Net 5` and `SQL Server` as Db. I have a simple model:

```
public class Model 
{
  public Guid Id { get; private set; }

  public decimal Value { get; private set; }

  public decimal Score { get; private set; }

  [ConcurrencyCheck]
  public StateEnum State { get; private set; }
}
```

Now I want concurrency check when I am updating `Value` property, but I don't need it when I update `Score` property (as it is updated frequently and is always overwritten).

Is there a way to disable concurrency check for some statements?

My reason being that concurrency checks adds additional overhead by fetching `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` but in some scenarios it's not needed. Also it raises exception and spams logs, but in case of `Score` update I don't care about the concurrency.

I come up with 2 solutions which I could implement, but maybe there is a better one:

1. do  `try{} catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex) {}` while this suppresses the exception from the check, the actual check is still happening and that extra overhead is not gone.
2. Split `Model` into 2 classes have `Score` in a separate class without concurrency check. (Maybe even pointing into the same Db table). While this could work it adds additional complexity to the system, especially when you need both `Score` and `Value`. So not ideal as well.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Hi, no, it was not critical, just a nice performance improvement, so it got postponed by other priorities. But if you will find something good, please share as an answer.